# Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\Glob' after install - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

After install I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\Glob' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proj\zobita\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Glob.php on line 14
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: run `composer update`. Make sure the file `vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/Glob.php` exists and is readable.

Comment: it ask repo.magento.com) this user name psw

Comment: @Kothari you installed a fresh Magento or there is any custom code?

Comment: Not a Fresh Magento In My old system it working fine then i try to configure my new system then only i got this error

Comment: Did you call `Zend\Stdlib\Glob` in somewheres in your custom code?

Comment: No it's them only it working my old system

Comment: Hey that's Magento 2 So that I added tag as Magento 2

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well after upgrading from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3. I don't know why, but for some reason the `vendor/zendrframework/zend-stdlib`-directory was empty.

After deleting the empty directory and running a `composer install` the library was installed and everything worked back fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use this command and solved.
composer install && composer update -vv && 
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;